# How can i use a float variable located within a Method in a separate ViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i am trying to pass a converted NSString value float to another ViewController so that is uses it to calculate the data stored in it.

```
-(IBAction) save:(id)sender {
NSString *inputField = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: self.inputField.text];
 float sf = [inputField floatValue];
 NSLog(@"The Value of inputField is %5.2f", sf);
```

}

This is just a shortened version of the code and well it saves the input value and stores it in an NSString and then converts it to a float value which then MUST be used in a firstViewController to be used in conjunction with a similar Converted NSString to a float Variable.

How can i use this:

```
  float sf;
```

in another ViewController but yet still holding its new Value to be decremented ? 
I can see this float value holds a value with the NSLog(@"%5.2f", sf); and would still like to use it somewhere aside from where it is originally implemented. Possibly in multiple ViewControllers.

Comment: :I can't understand wt you want. I think you want to pass float value to one viewController to another Am I correct?

Comment: YESSSS, This float value is located in my secondViewController.m and its inside a save method and i need this float value to be passed to my firstViewController.m to be used in a method there aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Singleton Pattern** and place your variable in that Singleton Class.. Use that variable through Singleton Instance from all-over your application.

It's a guideline to use **Singleton Pattern** wherever you want global variables.

**EDIT:**
Here are some helpful links of Singleton Tutorials for iOS:

1. [Singletons in Objective-C](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/#)
2. [3 ways to implement Singleton pattern in Objective-C](http://xperienced.com.pl/blog/3-ways-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-objective-c#)
3. [Fundamental iOS design patterns: SharedInstance](http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/12/19/fundamental-ios-design-patterns-sharedinstance-singleton-objective-c/#)

Comment: Singletons are new to me, any examples here ?

Comment: See the edited answer.. Singletons are easy to understand. You'll get complete grip on it after practicing it in your projects. It's better for you to get hold on different design patterns used for Efficient Software Development.

Comment: Great, I am gonna try the singletons since i have heard before that using the AppDelegate isnt a good practice and well it seems to be much easier.

Comment: Yes you should. Singleton Pattern isn't difficult to understand. :-)

Comment: Great, So i will definetly look into it now, Answers my question and will be useful to me in the long run, Thank you so much Salman Zaidi

Answer (score 0):

Declare the float as Property in app delegate 
as `@property float sf;` synthesize it.

then fill it up where u want and to acess this property u can use singelton of appdelegate in other view controller as

```
AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 NSLog(@"%@",delegate.sf);
```

Comment: AppDelegate is not a place to dump global variables. It's primary function is to catch application wide delegates callbacks.